# how to handle if else with range of values

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to execute this statement

```
$Data=$cash-$tax
```

The problem is that the tax differs for various ranges of cash

exactly as shown below.

cash range  ------------> tax

5,000 - 30,000-------->            700

30,001- 60,000-------- >          1,000

60,001 - 125,000 ------->        1,600

125,001  - 250,000 --------->      3,000

250,001  - 500,000 -------- >     5,000

500,001 -  1,000,000--------->     9,000

what code can i use to explain this. Ive tried if else

```
if($cash >=0 && <=30000) $tax=700;
elseif($cash >=30001 && <=60000) $tax=1000;
elseif($cash >=60001 && <=125000) $tax=1600;
elseif($cash >=125001 && <=250000) $tax=3000;
elseif($cash >=250001 && <=500000) $tax=5000;
else($cash >=500001 && <=1000000) $tax=9000;
endif
```

This is not working i dont know where the problem is.

Comment: Both sides of an `&&` have to be complete boolean comparisons: `$cash >=30001 && $cash <=60000` rather than `$cash >=30001 && <=60000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the full comparison expression for every item.

You can't do `if (($cash > 20) && (< 50))`. `$cash` must be part of every expression:

```
if($cash >=0 && $cash <=30000) $tax=700;
elseif($cash >=30001 && $cash <=60000) $tax=1000;
elseif($cash >=60001 && $cash <=125000) $tax=1600;
elseif($cash >=125001 && $cash <=250000) $tax=3000;
elseif($cash >=250001 && $cash <=500000) $tax=5000;
else($cash >=500001 &&$cash  <=1000000) $tax=9000;
endif
```

This gets really fun if you try to apply the same logic in Delete queries:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 1 OR 2;
```

Where did all my users go?